# Redis memory usage issue

Tags: performance, docker, spring-boot, redis

I have a cluster with two Redis docker instances (v3.2.5) I use for caching responses from Spring boot microservices.

I've disabled all persistence and the number of keys is stable over time, all of them expiring between 5 minutes and 1 day.

Despite this, I can see the memory usage creeping up. It looks like once a day (around midnight) it uses a lot of memory and then releases some of it. 
Does anyone have any idea what this process may be, if there's any way to configure Redis to avoid using that much memory?

[image: Redis memory usage]

The number of keys I have doesn't justify this amount of memory

[image]

**UPDATE**

After taking a snapshot of the database and loading the data on a fresh new Redis instance (same version, same config) the `memory_used_human` is 10 times lower than the original one.

Is it possible that key expiration doesn't really delete keys from memory?

Comment: Can you add the number of keys over time to the graph?

Comment: I don't have that data in the graph but the number of keys is normally constant, the ones expiring for the new ones being created.

Comment: I don't know if it explains your results, but it is [certainly](https://redis.io/commands/expire#how-redis-expires-keys) the case that "key expiration doesn't really delete keys from memory".

Comment: Thanks @KevinChristopherHenry. Interestingly, the docs say `All the keys that are already expired are deleted from the keyspace.`

Comment: The "all" in that sentence is referring to the keys that happen to be looked at during the probabilistic algorithm. "Periodically Redis tests **a few keys at random** among keys with an expire set. All the keys that are already expired are deleted from the keyspace."

Comment: After re-electing a new master node, the old master node seems to purge the keyspace and the memory consumption goes down dramatically